# Can't login to my laptop

Tags: laptop, passwords

Okay so i got some virus' on my laptop and decided to reset it and delete all my files. I had to start from scratch giving my name ans what not. But the day after i go to login and its asking me for a password for a different Microsoft account (my girlfriend's account... which she didnt know she had). I had just reset it the day before i hadnt put her login or email into my account. Nor did i before i reset it. So now i locked out of my laptop... anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: If you reset the PC and don't care about your personal files, what's stopping you from clean installing windows all together? That would get rid of any lingering accounts.

Answer (score 0):

No idea what version on windows you are but in the login screen look for "Switch User" and type the username and password you have previously created. Here in Windows 7 [Switch user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XiBtY.png)